# Extract property from function

Tags: r

Using code below I summarize a linear model :

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(1,2,3)

m = lm(y ~ x)
summary(m)
```

This prints :

```
 Call:
  lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
  1 2 3 
0 0 0 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        0          0      NA       NA    
x                  1          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic:   Inf on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
  In summary.lm(m) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

How to create new summary function which will just return the 'Coefficients' property :

```
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.874016   0.160143  -11.70   <2e-16 ***
  waiting      0.075628   0.002219   34.09   <2e-16 ***
```

here is my code :

```
tosum2 <- summary(m)
summary.myclass <- function(x)
{
  return(x$Coefficients)
}
class(tosum2) <- c('myclass', 'summary')
summary(tosum2)
```

but NULL is returned.

Update :

how can check available methods from summary function ( coef  is example of method available on summary) ? `methods(class="summary")` returns null

Comment: `broom::tidy(m)` is one option.

Comment: `coef(summary(m))`

Comment: Just use the existing `coef()` function: `coef(summary(m))`

Comment: ...and as others are recommending, using the `coef` function on the summary object is safer than trying to extract it yourself.

Comment: @joran how can check that coef is available ? methods(class="summary") returns null

Comment: You're looking for `methods(coef)` I think. `tidy` will likely handle a wider array of cases, fwiw.

Comment: @joran thanks, is there not a way to check all available methods on summary of which coef is one ? perhaps I need a new question....